# C++ Protected inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

ok so i've just encountered some weird problem.
i have the following code:

```
#pragma once
#include "Point.h"
#include "Shape.h"

class Polygon : public Shape{
public:
    Polygon(int = 0);
    Point& operator[] (int) const;
protected:
    Point *Points;
private:
    int Num_Of_Points;
};
```

Cpp file

```
Polygon::Polygon(int Num) : Num_Of_Points(Num) { Points = new Point[Num_Of_Points](); }
Point& Polygon::operator[] (int index) const{ return Points[index]; }
```

2nd header.

```
#pragma once
#include "Polygon.h"

class Triangle : public Polygon{
    Triangle(Point, Point, Point);
private:
    double Area;
};

Triangle::Triangle(Point A, Point B, Point C) : Polygon (3) {
    Points[0] = A;
    Points[1] = B;
    Points[2] = C;
}
```

now i get the following error at Triangle constructor:
Error   1   error C2248: 'Polygon::Points' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Polygon'

i cant understand why, Points is protected member and not private (i get the same error when i put it under public aswell)...

help would be much appriciated!

**EDIT:** forgot to mention, polygon is abstract class, it inherit from shape some abstract functions.

Comment: A small note unrelated to your question: Your `Triangly::Herons_Formula` does not override the function with the same name in the `Polygon` class. Instead it *overloads* it, while making the `Polygon::Herons_Formula` inaccessible for instances of the `Triangle` class.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/0D8F1v). Please post a complete example. Leave out the irrelevant functions.

Comment: yeah i know i didnt get to Herons_Formula yet, there should be some changes, thinking how to implement it.
maybe you could help me with this issue aswell.
i have rectangle and Triangle classes aswell that inherit from Polygon.
now Polygon is abstract class but i want to use the same Horns_Formula function on them both.
Horns_Formula need to get 3 indexes so the implementation is the same for triangle and rectangle give or take
so how can i implement it in Polygon and use it from triangle and rectangle ?
(hope you understood the problem)

Comment: The code you have works.  Voting to close.

Comment: @Itay.V That's not complete, and adding trivial implementations of the missing parts produces no error. You need to post code that produces the error. (Compile it yourself first to make sure.)

Comment: @molbdnilo it does produce errors for me...
Error 1 error C2248: 'Polygon::Points' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Polygon'
it says it cannot access private..

are you guys sure it works for you ? should i try to open new project and copy paste maybe ?

Comment: @Itay.V The code you posted does indeed [produce several errors](http://ideone.com/YY3dbK), but not one of them is the one you claim.

Comment: ok it works now, openned new project. can close.

Comment: In the future, please post a [mcve].